# How can i compare unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following and i want to test for equality -

```python
id_0 = 40
id_1 = 48
id_2 = 49
id_3 = 41
id_4 = 0

conc_value = chr(id_0)+chr(id_1)+chr(id_2)+chr(id_3)+chr(id_4)

if conc_value == '(01)':
    print('Match')
else:
    print('Mismatch')
```

I always get a mismatch. How can i compare the 2 values?

Comment: Drop the 0 at the end.

Comment: `'(01)\x00'` Would also work. Did you try printing `repr(conc_value)` to see if it matched your expectation?

Comment: I cannot drop the 0 since that is a random stuff sent by an external system. Is there a way to filter them out ?

Comment: If your external system uses binary data, it is better to use Python's `bytes`, `bytearray` and `struct` to work with them.

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve, instead of trying to make sense of your incorrect solution?

Answer (score 0):

Python strings aren't NUL-terminated. Don't add `chr(id_4)` to the string, and this works. Or change the literal being compared to to `'(01)\0'` (though it would be very unusual to want a NUL "terminator" in a string that doesn't use them).

If your data is coming from an external system (we'll imagine a function `get_ordinal` that returns the next Unicode ordinal from the external system by some means, and raises a custom `NoMoreData` exception when there's nothing left), then just filter the values as they come in:

```
ordinals = []  # List to store ordinals in
bad_ordinals = frozenset(map(ord, '\x00ÿ'))  # Make set of invalid ordinals for cheap exclusion test
try:
    while True:
        ordinal = get_ordinal()
        if ordinal not in bad_ordinals:
            ordinals.append(ordinal)  # Only append if not on blocklist
except NoMoreData:
    pass
conc_data = ''.join(map(chr, ordinals))  # Bulk convert to characters then efficiently
                                         # glue together final string
```

Comment: there are other fields which can be 0 and i have to concatenate them as they are coming from an external system. Is there a way to remove the rest like `\\u0000` or `ÿÿÿÿ`

Comment: @Dan: You need to be more specific about what you're doing here. The obvious solution is to make a list of these Unicode ordinals, and filter out what you don't want, e.g. if `ordinals = [40, 48,49, 41]` and `blocklist = '\x00ÿ'`, you can do `conc_value = ''.join([c for c in map(chr, ordinals) if c not in blocklist])` which converts to individual characters, filters out the ones in your list of invalid characters, then joins them all together (efficiently, unlike repeated concatenation with `+`) into the final string. Without a more clear example of what you're *really* doing, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

```
id_0 = 40
id_1 = 48
id_2 = 49
id_3 = 41

conc_value = chr(id_0)+chr(id_1)+chr(id_2)+chr(id_3)+chr(id_4)

if conc_value.replace("\0", "") == '(01)':
    print('Match')
else:
    print('Mismatch')

#Match
```

This because you do not need the null char to end strings in python

Comment: i am getting those ids from an external system and i need to concatenate those as they can have valid values. Is there a way to remove the rest like `\\u0000` or `ÿÿÿÿ`

Comment: ok I get it. I edited my answer. In the `if` statement I am comparing the string without the `chr(0)` character with `'(01)'`

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco: FYI, `'\0'` (or `'\x00'`) is a much simpler way to spell the NUL character, and unlike `chr(0)`, doesn't involve Python calling `chr` over and over for each call if you do it many times (string literals can be stored in the constants and loaded with a simple C array lookup, while function calls are much more expensive, even though, in this case, as an implementation detail, converting `0` to `'\0'` ultimately devolves to a C array lookup in the cached array of length 1 `latin-1` strings).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are right. I'm editing my answer with your hint.